# Умножить каждый элемент двумерного массива

Tags: python, массивы, матрицы

есть такая матрица:

```
 import numpy as np
 a=np.array ([[0, 2.4, -6, 5, 0.8], 
              [1.5, 0, 0, -4.3, -3.5], 
              [0, 1.8, 3.2, -1.2, -1.3],
              [0, 0, -2.3, 0, -7.2],
              [3.3 -0.8, 0, 3.5, 8]])
```

нужно сделать новую матрицу каждый элемент умножить на 5.9
и вывести массив на экран

так же нужно найти минимальный элемент каждой строчки матрицы и вывести его значение и индекс

Comment: слушайте, это же самые начальные знания по numpy, вы хотите, чтобы мы учебник сюда переписали?

Comment: Извините, не нашёл в гугле как умножить каждый элемент двумерного массива на не целое число

Comment: `b = a * 5.9` вот это не нашли?

Comment: пытался https://prnt.sc/lNTch_8gRBCC

Comment: А на будущее, если вы что-то пробовали, но получили ошибку - приводите это всё тоже в вопросе, не стесняйтесь. А то сейчас получается комментаторы думают, что вы не разобрались в тривиальном случае и даже минусуют вопрос (видимо, по этой причине), а у вас вообще другая проблема на самом деле.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас на самом деле проблема в другом - в пропущенной запятой вот здесь:

```
[3.3 -0.8, 0, 3.5, 8]])
   ^^^
```

Если поставить там запятую, то массив станет "квадратным" и умножение его на `5.9` уже не будет давать ту ошибку, которую вы получаете сейчас при попытке умножения, и которая вас сбила с толку:

```
b = a * 5.9

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Из-за отсутствия запятой у вас сейчас получается массив из списков разной длины и не получается сделать нормальную `numpy` матрицу - внутри массива `numpy` по-прежнему лежат обычные питоновские списки, и вот именно их можно "умножать" только на целые числа. Но это всё-равно не то умножение, которое вы думаете.